# Cannot get the children of a div using Puppeteer page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, html, dom, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate uploading an image to imgur using Puppeteer. I have successfully implemented the uploading, but now I want to get the raw image URL of the uploaded image.

To do that, I inspected the html and found out that the uploaded image is displayed in a div which has the following markup.

```html
<div class="PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZOQgT6A.png">
</div>
```

Therefore, to obtain that, I wrote some puppeteer code as follows.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(request.query.url);
let imgPath = nanoid() + ".png"
await page.screenshot({ path: imgPath });

// imgur image upload
const pg = await browser.newPage();
pg.on("console", (consoleObj) => {
    if (!['warning','error'].includes(consoleObj.type())) {
      console.log(consoleObj.text());
    }
  })
  await pg.goto("https://imgur.com/upload");
  const elementHandle = await pg.$("input[type=file]");
  await elementHandle.uploadFile(imgPath);
  await pg.waitForTimeout(5000)
  await pg.waitForSelector('.PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded')
  let imgSrc = await pg.evaluate(function(){
    let dd = "undefined";
    while (dd === "undefined" || dd[0] === "undefined"){
      dd = document.getElementsByClassName("PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded")
    }
    return dd[0].firstChild.src // getting different errors time to time
  })
  console.log(imgSrc)
  await browser.close();
  fs.unlink(imgPath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
  })
```

However, this code fails at the line indicated by a comment, throwing the following error.

> Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'firstChild')\n    at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:3:18

But when I execute the same JS code inside the `evaluate` function, in the browser, it works and returns the image raw URL. So I'm really frustrated about why this doesn't work.

[image]

Can you give me some suggestions to overcome this problem and copy the raw image URL without problems? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe the element is not loaded yet? try await page.waitForSelector('.PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded') before

Comment: You use wrong variable) You need `let imgs = await pg.evaluate(function(){` instead of `let imgs = await page.evaluate(function(){`. Also `return dd` will always return an empty object into puppeteer context as element collection is not serializable. So just return `dd[0].firstChild.src` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    let dd = "undefined";
    while (dd === "undefined" || dd[0] === "undefined"){
      dd = document.getElementsByClassName("PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded")
    }
```

This loop blocks event loop and prevents the DOM from updating. So maybe try this instead:

```js
  await pg.waitForSelector('.PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded > img');
  let imgSrc = await pg.evaluate(function(){
    let img = document.querySelector('.PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded > img');
    return img.src;
  });
  console.log(imgSrc);
```